# Why double is not allowed in in-class initializer

Tags: c++, oop

I have been reading "Exceptional C++" by Herb Shutter, "Item 1 : #define or const and inlining [...]".

It is said that the in-class initialization is allowed only for integral types(integers,chars,bools)  and only for constants..

I just want to know why double/float cannot be initialized in class declaration.
Are there any specific reasons?

```
class EngineeringConstants {      // this goes in the class
 private:                          // header file
  static const double FUDGE_FACTOR;
  ...
 };
 // this goes in the class implementation file
 const double EngineeringConstants::FUDGE_FACTOR = 1.35;
```

I just want to know the reason why the below declaration is not allowed:

```
class EngineeringConstants {      // this goes in the class
 private:                          // header file
  static const double FUDGE_FACTOR = 1.35;
  ...
 };
```

?

Answer (score 18):

This statement is outdated: in C++03 initialization using `double`s in the class definition was not supported. In C++ (starting with the 2011 revision), you can initialize arbitrary members in the class definition. Also, the initialization isn't limited to `static` members but you can also initialize non-`static` members:

```
struct foo {
    static constexpr double value = 1.23;
    std::string   str = "foo";
};
```

The historic reason to prohibit initialization of `static` members using floating point numbers in C++03 was that the numeric during compilation could be different than those during execution. For example, when cross compiling on a platform using IEEE floating points and targeting a platform using IBM hex floats could yield different results even for constants representable in both numeric systems.

Comment: "In C++, you can (...)", C++0x

Comment: @computer: the current official C++ standard is INCITS/ISO/IEC 14882-2011. Earlier version may still be in use but this doesn't mean that the _current_ version of the standard should be referred to in funny ways.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: I think writing C++11 (instead of just C++) doesn't harm. It will benefits those who want to learn which version of C++ this has been changed. Say, in 2017, people will read this answer and will immediately know that it has been changed since C++11 (not C++14 or C++17).

Comment: @Nawaz: I do think it _does_ harm because it implies that C++11 is something different than C++ while it is not. C++ is distinctly **not** C++03 and we shall qualify the outdated versions rather than the current versions! That is the choice of "C++" rather than "C++11" you changed the answer to was actually deliberate.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: C++11 implies version also, C++ doesn't. How does it harm?

Comment: "C++" doesn't imply current C++ standard, especially "In C++", it doesn't harm, and we should always make our best to clearify things as much as it could be done (specially if with no cost) IMO

Comment: @computer C++ *does* imply the current standard, otherwise what could it imply? If you want to specify an older standard, then you can be explicit about it (C++98, C++03, C++11 once C++14 comes out...)

Comment: @Nawaz: if we consistently label _all_ versions and don't single out the current as being somewhat odd, it may not harm. However, I see people singling out C++11 (e.g. there is a c++11 tag but there are no c++03 or c++98 tags) and _that_ is wrong and harmful as it implies that C++11 is something different than C++!

Comment: @DietmarKühl: Please remember that the definition of "current version" changes with time. Say I'm reading this answer in 2022 and wondering which "current version" of C++ are you talking about? I'm also wondering since which version this has been changed? "C++" will not answer my question in 2022, but C++11 clarifies everything.

Comment: @Nawaz: I don't buy into this changing argument as the question and answer are labeled with the date at which they were written. It seems, this may be a discussion which should be had but probably not on the back of this answer...

Comment: in short: doesn't harm, might help. why do you so blindly adhere not to give someone this hint, this is ridiculous. also please note: this site is also for absolute beginners

Comment: @DietmarKühl because this is fact indeed that "C++11 is something different than C++", maybe something like "POD array" and "array"

Comment: @computer: as I stated, if we consistently label all versions and do **not** single out the current standard as being odd and labeling that one as special I wouldn't mind. My key here is: C++11 _is_ [currently] C++. C++03 is **not** C++ [anymore].

Comment: @DietmarKühl: The "date" (on which you posted this answer) is NOT part of the answer: in 2022, you want me to read the date of the post, and *infer* the version of C++ from it? **That clearly means your answer doesn't clarify it**.

Comment: @Nawaz: in this particular case the answer will still be correct, even without the date on the standard version of C++: the current version of C++ in 2022 will [almost certainly] allow initialization of members in the class. However, I singled out that C++03 does not support it (that fact will not change). So, is my answer correct only for C++11 or also for C++14, C++17, ..or for C++ [as it currently is] in general? Which is the correct spelling of where the initialization is supported? Does someone reading the answer in two years wonder if the initialization is not supported in C++14 anymore?

Comment: @juanchopanza: *"C++ does imply the current standard, otherwise what could it imply?"*. I'm reading this answer in 2022, so which version of C++ does *"current standard"* mean (when the rule has been changed)? Still "current" version (in 2022 also)?

Comment: @DietmarKühl: Please talk about the "harm". "C++11" will tell me the version in which the rule has been changed, but "C++" will not tell me (assuming I'm reading it in 2022). So I don't see harm in mentioning "C++11" where it helps!

Comment: @Nawaz: are things applicable to C++11 also applicable to C++14? It seems, C++ says it is applicable to C++ in general and not to any particular version of C++ as C++11 implies. I consider this harmful. I also consider it harmful to create the impression that C++11 is something different than C++.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: I'm repeating myself:  *"C++11" will tell me the version **in which the rule has been changed**, but "C++" will not tell me (assuming I'm reading it in 2022). So I don't see harm in mentioning "C++11" where it helps!* **(Yes, C++11 is different from all other versions, there is no harm in saying it is different. In fact it is good thing to know.)**.

Comment: `static double value = 1.23;` I'm pretty sure this is not allowed. See [class.static.data]/3. I'm using N3485, and it allows `const static` integral+enumeration types, plus `constexpr` literal types to be initialized in the class definition.

Comment: @DyP: you are right - a `constexpr` is missing (correcting in a second).

Comment: I think the "you can initialize arbitrary members in the class definition" is still misleading. You can only initialize static data members inside the class definition which can be used in constant expressions, essentially (excluding references).